# Tramp resets file buffer encoding to UTF

Tags: tramp, character-encoding

I edit my files in cp1251 encoding.

This works fine on local host but when I save files on remote host using tramp it resets encoding to utf-8 constantly.

Even if I do `(set-buffer-file-coding-system)` to cp1251, it sets the encoding for awhile, but after saving the file it immediately resets to utf-8.  The saved file appears in cp1251 as desired, but the buffer encoding becomes utf-8 and subsequent saving appears in utf-8

For example,
I do
`(set-buffer-file-coding-system 'cp1251)`

save file

the file on disk is in cp1251 encoding, but the encoding flag in the left bottom becomes U for utf-8

save file again

it is in utf-8 encoding

It happens regardless of if the file contains only ASCII symbols or non-ASCII symbols.
I use Win 10

The issue appeared in emacs 29.1, everything was ok in 28.1

workaround

```
(defun set-remote-encoding ()
  "set buffer encoding to cp1251"
    (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'cp1251))

(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'set-remote-encoding)
```

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in Emacs 29? If you don't get a helpful answer here, maybe try `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Yes, please write a bug report. There is bug#64164 (https://debbugs.gnu.org/64164), which looks similar. Needs to be investigated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it turns out to be a bug in Tramp, see bug#65022. It has been fixed, will be available with Emacs 29.2. The GNU ELPA package Tramp 2.1.6.2 will contain this fix as well.